# Find value for each subject and save as new table

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame with long format data as follows

```
ID Frame.No ROI.No Flux.med
01 1        1      78
01 1        2      76
01 2        1      80
01 2        2      80
01 3        1      89
01 3        2      80
27 1        1      60
27 1        2      68
27 4        1      80
27 4        2      89
```

For each "ID" I want to get the first and maximum Flux.med for both ROI 1 and 2 and put all these in a new dataframe. If I have a dataframe with just one subject (e.g. ID 01) I am able to identify the Flux.med values I need using the following code:

```
ROI1.baseline <-  mydata %>%
    filter(ROI.No == "ROI 1" & Frame.No == min(Frame.No))%>%   
  select(Flux.Med)

ROI1.max <-  mydata%>%
     filter(ROI.No == "ROI 1")%>%
  filter (Flux.Med == max(Flux.Med))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)

ROI2.baseline <-  mydata%>%
  filter(ROI.No == "ROI 2" & Frame.No == min(Frame.No))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)

ROI.max <-  mydata%>%
   filter(ROI.No == "ROI 2")%>%
  filter (Flux.Med == max(Flux.Med))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)
```

But I need to do that for each ID and save the results in a dataframe.

Can I do this with a `for` loop?

Comment: Thank you. I did it my longer way in the end, though in hindsight I could have used your dplyr way and filtered/sorted later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. So this is how I did it in the end:

```
ROI1.baseline <-  ldi_data %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(ROI.No == "ROI 1" & Frame.No == min(Frame.No))%>%   ###uses lowest number frame as baseline (not necessarily frame 1 if it was excluded)
  select(Flux.Med)%>%
  dplyr::rename(ROI1_baseline = Flux.Med)%>%
  as.data.frame(ROI1.baseline)

ROI1.max <-  ldi_data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(ROI.No == "ROI 1")%>%
  filter (Flux.Med == max(Flux.Med))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)%>%
  dplyr::rename(ROI1_max = Flux.Med)%>%
  as.data.frame(ROI1.max)

ROI2.baseline <-  ldi_data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(ROI.No == "ROI 2" & Frame.No == min(Frame.No))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)%>%
  dplyr::rename(ROI2_baseline = Flux.Med)%>%
  as.data.frame(ROI2.baseline)

ROI2.max <-  ldi_data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(ROI.No == "ROI 2")%>%
  filter (Flux.Med == max(Flux.Med))%>%
  select(Flux.Med)%>%
  dplyr::rename(ROI2_max = Flux.Med)%>%
  as.data.frame(ROI2.max)

summary <-   Reduce(merge, list(ROI1.baseline, ROI1.max, ROI2.baseline, ROI2.max))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get first and `max` value in each `ID` and `ROI.No`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(ID, ROI.No) %>%
  summarise(first_flux = first(Flux.med), 
             max_flux = max(Flux.med))

#    ID ROI.No first_flux max_flux
#  <int>  <int>      <int>    <int>
#1     1      1         78       89
#2     1      2         76       80
#3    27      1         60       80
#4    27      2         68       89
```

Or using `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(Flux.med~ID + ROI.No, mydata, function(x) c(first = x[1], max = max(x)))
```

**data**

```
mydata <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L), Frame.No = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), ROI.No = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Flux.med = c(78L, 76L, 80L, 
80L, 89L, 80L, 60L, 68L, 80L, 89L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(first_flux = first(Flux.med), 
         max_flux = max(Flux.med)), .(ID, ROI.No)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L), Frame.No = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), ROI.No = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Flux.med = c(78L, 76L, 80L, 
80L, 89L, 80L, 60L, 68L, 80L, 89L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```